# How do I change the search location for keycloak.json in keycloak-spring-security-adapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

Spring Boot 2.6.4

```
Loading Keycloak deployment from configuration file: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/keycloak.json]
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter' defined in class path resource [de/icod/blog/configuration/SecurityConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in class path resource [de/icod/blog/configuration/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception;
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
```

I followed the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter) and copy pasted everything.

The error message says that it can't find `/WEB-INF/keycloak.json`. That is correct. I don't have a WEB-INF directory in the spring boot generated project.
**How can I change the location where `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` is looking for this file?**

If I add the following to the `SecurityConfig` I'm getting a circular dependency error.

```java
@Bean
public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}
```

I have also created <project_root>/WEB-INF/keycloak.json with the same error message.

I'm starting to wonder if Spring Security != Spring Boot Security.

Feedback: I have to say that the documentation isn't very good. For instance `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` doesn't explain how to get claims from a request. Just "securing" endpoints isn't enough. You also have to use that information somehow, maybe in an interceptor.

**UPDATE**: This question is "solved" for me, but the answer remains open and while I'm sure there is an answer to this question it's not an easy one.

Comment: https://medium.com/keycloak/secure-spring-boot-2-using-keycloak-f755bc255b68
or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796450/4373948

Comment: This helped with how to get the claims. Ultimately I don't think there's an easy answer to this question. What I learned though is that `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` alone is enough but if you want all the additional features of spring security `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` is REQUIRED.

When I put the above `@Bean` into a separate `BeanConfig` class the circular dependency issue was gone.

So now it's working for me, but the question remains unanswered and will probably stay so, which is ok.

Java and Spring/boot ecosystem is a mess for someone new or even semi new to the story. ty.