# Testing a Spring controller secured with Keycloak

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, keycloak

I am trying to write a few tests for my Spring controller. The endpoints are secured with Keycloak (open id connect).

I tried mocking an authenticated user using the `@WithMockUser` annotation but I need to retrieve claims from the token (preferred_username) and I end up getting a null pointer exception from here:

```
return Long.parseLong(((KeycloakPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getPreferredUsername());
```

Is there any way to mock the Keycloak token? I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144953/mocking-a-keycloak-token-for-testing-a-spring-controller) similar question but I do not want to use the [suggested](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) external library.

Thank you guys in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: Already asked (and answered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199105/how-to-unit-test-a-springboot-controller-secured-by-keycloak?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I came across this similar question but I do not want to use the suggested external library.

Well, you'd better reconsider that.

Are you using the [deprecated Keycloak adapters](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187)?

If yes, and if you still don't want to use `spring-addons-keycloak`, you'll have to manualy populate test security context with a `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` instance or mock:

```java
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final var principal = mock(Principal.class);
        when(principal.getName()).thenReturn("user");

        final var account = mock(OidcKeycloakAccount.class);
        when(account.getRoles()).thenReturn(Set.of("offline_access", "uma_authorization"));
        when(account.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);

        final var authentication = mock(KeycloakAuthenticationToken.class);
        when(authentication.getAccount()).thenReturn(account);

        // post(...).with(authentication(authentication))
        // limits to testing secured @Controller with MockMvc
        // I prefer to set security context directly instead:
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        //TODO: invoque mockmvc to test @Controller or test any other type of @Component as usual
    }
```

You'll soon understand why this `@WithMockKeycloakAuth` was created.

If you already migrated to something else than Keycloak adapters, solution with manualy setting test-security context still applies, just adapt the `Authentication` instance. If your authentication type is `JwtAuthenticationToken`, you can use either:

- `jwt()` request post processor for MockMvc I wrote (it is available from [`spring-security-test`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/oauth2.html#testing-jwt))

```
    @Test
    void testWithPostProcessor() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet").with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> {
            jwt.claim("preferred_username", "Tonton Pirate");
        }).authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("NICE_GUY"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("AUTHOR")))))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hi Tonton Pirate! You are granted with: [NICE_GUY, AUTHOR]."));
    }
```

- `@WithMockJwtAuth`, same author, [different lib](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)

```
    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = { "NICE_GUY", "AUTHOR" }, claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void testWithPostProcessor() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hi Tonton Pirate! You are granted with: [NICE_GUY, AUTHOR]."));
    }
```

Note that only second option will work if you want to unit-test a secured `@Component` that is not a `@Controller` (a `@Service` or `@Repository` for instance).

My two cent advices:

- drop Keycloak adapters now: it will disapear soon, is not adapted to boot 2.7+ (web-security config should not extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` any more) and is way too adherent to Keycloak. Just have a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) to see how easy it can be to configure **and unit-test** a JWT resource-server (with identities issued by Keycloak or any other OIDC authorization-server)
- if your team does not let you abandon Keycloak adapters yet, use `@WithMockKeycloakAuth`, you'll save tones of time and your test code will be way more readable.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with manually populating the security context. I personally would have used your library but sadly it is not entirely up to me. Also thank you for the extra advice.

Comment: You can present the argument this lib has the same author as JWT unit-testing support in Spring's `spring-security-test` (jwt() MockMvc post-processor and WebTestClient mutator). Plus, this are libs imported with `test` scope => note there at runtime...